# Mining with a GTX 1080 and Radeon 570 on the same machine

Tags: mining, genoil

So currently I am able to mine with either one on their own by specifying the --opencl-platform, if I try to run them both then it crashes when it is "Grabbing DAG for ...".  I am using --no-precompute, and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled geth and ethereum in a separate location on my machine and used the --dag-dir option to select another location.  Now it is generating another DAG file.  I'll update this if it works.  This also could have had something to do with me not running as administrator before.

EDIT: It is working now, I think just having the separate DAG file is what did it.